# Deriving sequence of roots from sequence of polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

For $0<x<1$ and $N\in \mathbb{N}$, I have the following sequence of polynomials:
$$
P_N(x)=(2x-1)^{2N}-4x^{2N}+1
$$

I want to calculate the sequence of real roots in interval $x_N \in [0.5,1)$. In the
end I want to figure out if $\lim_{N \to \infty} x_N = 1$.

I have calculated roots for $\forall N<20$ numerically and it seems like there is always on real root in said interval and it approaches 1 .

Is my problem solvable analytically?

Comment: I didn't look for the convergence of the roots, but indeed you can prove that there is a unique root (for N>0) in your interval. Just check that $P_N(\frac{1}{2}) >0$ and $P_N(1)<0$. Then you have a root in your interval by the intermediate value theorem. For the unicity, have a look at $P'_N(x)$ on the interval and you should see (using the bounds on $x$) that it is non positive (notice that on $[\frac{1}{2};1]$ : $\frac{(2x-1)^k}{4x^k}\leqslant 1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$). I'll let you know if i think about something for the convergence.

Comment: It looks like $$x_N=(2-\sqrt{3})^\frac1{2N}+O\left(N^{-2}\right),$$ but the technical details are a bit... tedious. Is it important, or mere curiosity?